# How do I remove a point from an OpenLayer LineString from a Modify Interaction (used to be able to click a point to remove)

Tags: openlayers

I've just upgraded OpenLayers 3.x to 4.6.5.

I used to be able to remove a point in a line using the mouse. I would set up a modify interaction, and then I could add points by clicking someone within the line, or remove points by clicking on an existing point.

In 4.6.5, I can add lines, but cannot remove them any more.

Was there a change in the UI? Or, is this a bug?

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: You can specify a delete condition.  The default is clicking on the vertex with the ALT key pressed https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.interaction.Modify.html

Comment: Thank Mike - I searched the docs but couldn't find that! Thanks for the reference :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mike's answer in the comments gave me the answer I was hoping for. The default is clicking on the vertex with the ALT key pressed

https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.interaction.Modify.html